# How to link two usercontrols? WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, user-controls

I have a main window that links to a usercontrol with two buttons depending on the one selected I want these buttons to display another usercontrol. Below is the code for the button - the second usercontrol does not display but the first was hidden.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewTruckUC addNewTruckUC = new AddNewTruckUC();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            addNewTruckUC.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

These user controls are being displayed in a stack panel on the home form.

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: what is the class that Button_Click event handler in?

Comment: ExistingModelOrNew

Comment: Is that the code behind of the main window or what?

Comment: thats the name of the class sorry all this class has is a button even handler.

Comment: the stackpanel code is part of the main window code

Comment: Please explain, does the buttons also exist on the MainWindow?

Comment: There is a main window with a button in the menu that says add truck. Once this is clicked the usercontrol existingmodelornew appears in the stackpanel. This usercontrol has two buttons which both should open a new usercontrol. The code above is for the first button on this usercontrol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238882/discussion-between-sabsab-and-baldeep-sahdra).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating an instance of a UserControl but not setting it to the StackPanelMain or to any other container.

There is plenty ways to implement what you intend.

One way is:

In your MainWindow constructor instantiate the user controls

```
AddNewTruckUC addNewTruckUC;
ExistingModelOrNew existingModelOrNew;
Public MainWindow()
{
    addNewTruckUC = new AddNewTruckUC();
    existingModelOrNew = new ExistingModelOrNew()
}
```

The buttons should be in the MainWindow class not in the UserControls since the MainWindow has the StackPanelMain object.

```
private void ButtonShowAddNew(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanelMain.Children.Add(addNewTruckUC);
    StackPanelMain.Children.Remove(existingModelOrNew);
}

private void ButtonShowExisting(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanelMain.Children.Add(existingModelOrNew);
    StackPanelMain.Children.Remove(addNewTruckUC);
}
```

This might not be the exact scenario of your logic but this shows the problem.

Instantiating a user control does not show it anywhere. You have to add it manually to the intended place.